# Dynamic axis labels with power Pivot

Tags: excel, powerpivot

I am working with Excel and Powerpivot. In my data layer I have two tables related, in the main table I have my data and the ID that refers to my second table which is a reference table containing (Description, short description, units, abbreviation,..)
Simplified example:

```
Table 1:
Name        Year   Value   Indicator
Usain Bolt  2009    9.58       1
Mike Powell 1990    8.95       2

Table 2:
ID Discipline Short_Descr Unit 
1  100 metres  100m        seconds
2  Long Jump   L. j.       metres
```

I want to create a chart where the axis and title are dynamic using the values in the reference table. The dynamic title is quite easy to build: I create my pivot chart using as Report filter the Description, and then I reference the chat title to this filter. But I would like to include in the vartical axis dinamically the units. So if I change the filter the units in the axis also change